# Connection Problem with update

Tags: updates, package-management, synaptic

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to install synaptic package manager using
`sudo apt-get update`.
This command has stuck at 0%.

I use a network proxy setting. 
Internet is not working in Update manager, Terminal etc. Its only working in Firefox.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your computer?, Router?, And What Have You Tried so Far? Are You Able to access the internet through A Browser?

Comment: yes I have tried all this options and yes I am able to browse..

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: attach error log if you got any..

Comment: No I am not getting any error..it just not working in any other place than firefox...is it due to proxy settings?

Comment: Where did you set the proxy? Did you set it on System level or in firefox only?

Comment: I have set it in System level

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might be occurred due to misconfiguration proxy in system level

(1) Open Dash -> Type "Network" and open setting as follows.

[image]

(2) Select Network proxy

(3) Select Method as manual

(4) Write your proxy address in all the text boxes with port number.

(5) Don't forget to apply it by clicking "Apply system wide"

(6) You'll be prompted to provide your password. provide it.

(7) After that go to your shell and try `sudo apt-get update`

Hope this will work for you. Thanks.